# how to handle cancelled and failed states of AVAssetWriter?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avassetwriter

Some of my users experience crash when they finish recording video.  I setup everything correctly and this is happening only for %0.2 of the users. The crash happens when `finishWriting` is called.

I finally decide to check AVAssetWriter's status before I call below code;

```
videoInput?.markAsFinished()
videoWriter?.finishWriting
```

now it is;

```
if videoWriter?.status == .writing {
            videoInput?.markAsFinished()
            videoWriter?.finishWriting 
             // some ui configurations
}
```

**But what about the other cases `.cancelled` & `.failed` ? Is it necessary to call the following code again? What should I do if videoWriter?.status == .cancelled or videoWriter?.status == .failed?**

```
videoInput?.markAsFinished()
videoWriter?.finishWriting
```

Comment: I'm struggling with this too. The documentation specifies that "To ensure the asset writer finishes writing all samples, call this method only after all calls to append(_:) or append(_:withPresentationTime:) return." Maybe that can help?

Comment: it did not help unfortunately at the time. It was totally aligned with the documentation. However, we did not work more on this since the feature was removed later on.